# Custom interpreter for mathematical expressions

Tags: c++, c, parsing, interpreter

I have to evaluate a large number of expressions containing variables and I am thinking about writing a small custom interpreter to keep compilation fast and small. However I have no experience with this topic and have a few questions.

Say we have a file with mathematical expressions and a limited set of objects. The file could look like:

```
expr[x,y,z] = 2*x*y + x^2 + 28/14*z*(x*y^2 + 15*z) + ...
```

I'd like to parse this somehow so I can evaluate the expressions numerically in my application 
by simply calling a function `expr(float x, float y, float z)`. The number of parameters should not be fixed (**EDIT -:** every expression would have its own definition with the appropriate number of parameters or would accept an array) and nesting of parenthesis should be allowed to keep the input files reasonably small.

Since the expressions are all of polynomial type, I can think of how the data structure should look like, but parsing looks difficult. I have already found some answers to somewhat similar questions here on SO, for instance using `Lua`.

The biggest question, however, is what the performance penalty would be when creating and calling those objects as compared to directly compile these expressions from automatically generated C code.

Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT -:** Please consider the example of `expr()` above only as such. I guess the best way would be to have objects of a template class that holds coefficients and powers of the variables in sparse arrays.

Comment: "calling a function expr(float x, float y, float z). The number of parameters should not be fixed" - you've got a bit of a problem there, then, since the number of parameters in a C or C++ function call *is* fixed. Even with varargs, where the callee can cope with different numbers, the caller has to fix the number at compile time. You're probably going to need to pass an array instead.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Fixed, I'm aware of this.

Comment: Why don't you just write your function expression as a C function, and compile/run it?

Answer (score 6):

Performance is a bit of a length-of-a-piece-of-string issue. Interpreted languages pretty much always are slower than compiled C code to evaluate arithmetic expressions. But not that many programs spend the majority of their time doing arithmetic, so most of the time that doesn't matter. It also makes a difference whether you parse the expression every time you evaluate it or (as seems more likely from what you say), parse it into some intermediate form.

It's impossible to tell from what you've said, whether it will matter to you, or how fast an interpreter you will write, but I wouldn't expect it to be better than 10 times slower, as far as time spent evaluating the expressions is concerned. First attempts at interpretation have been far worse.

As for that intermediate form - the usual place to start is to use Dijkstra's "shunting-yard" algorithm to convert your infix expressions to a reverse Polish form. That gives you a sequence of "symbols", "byte codes", call them what you like, and it's easy to write an expression evaluator for that form - each operator just pops its operands from a stack, performs the op, then pushes the result onto the stack, until the final value of the expression is the only thing left at the end. Numeric literals and variable names are just like "operators" that pop no operands, and push their value.

[Edit - depending who your users are, it might be feasible for your program to take that text file, generate a C program from it, run a compiler and then run the resulting program (or, open and call into the resulting dll). Obviously that relies on a lot of system-specific stuff (a compiler being installed, for one), and the expressions would need to be evaluated enough times that the overhead of compilation is overcome.]

Comment: Thank you for your input. So here's the point: The expressions consist of sometimes thousands of terms (with up to 15 parameters) and should be evaluated over and over again for different parameter values. Parsing should be done only once. Thinking about your suggestion to push to and pop from a stack, I guess my question is: Is this the right way to do if the expressions are always polynomial? Would there be a performance penalty (apart from the initial parsing) at all if I'd try to implement this as in my second EDIT?

Comment: @bbrtb: what's described in your second edit would typically be somewhat slower than the same expression written in C. Firstly because there's some overhead to accessing the sparse structure that tells you the powers and coefficients, secondly because C compilers come with kick-ass optimizers. Really simple example, if your polynomial contains repeated sub-expressions then a C optimizer will likely spot them and avoid duplicate work, but the evaluator you write that takes an array of coefficients will have a hard time being anything like so smart.

Comment: I see, still looks like it's worth a try. What I could do to optimize this to some extend is to nest the polynomial objects. The input I have is as in my post, so it's already simplified as it's generated with Mathematica.

Comment: @bbrtb: simplified isn't the same as re-using intermediate results of repeated sub-expressions. The example you show contains `x*y` and also `x*y^2`, which presumably we'd translate into C as `x*y*y`. So `x*y` could potentially be calculated only once and re-used, *or* if `y*y` occurs elsewhere and we don't mind ignoring the fact that float multiplication isn't really associative, that could be reused instead. C compiler-writers have spent more time thinking about such things than you or I likely ever will.

Comment: oh I'm sure and I really don't want to dive too deep into this mess.

Answer (score 1):

You stated the problem as "big complex expressions", and you are concerned about performance penalties.  Then you should consider compiling them, not interpreting them.
(good interpreters are 10x slower than compiled code as a rule of thumb; lousy/ad hoc interpreters tend to be significantly worse).

The usual route for this is to "compile" the expressions somehow, which involves building parsers, code generators, optimizations, etc.

C compilers already do all this.  So I think
you'd be far better off translating these expressions to C. 
Compiling them is then easy and execution will be lightning fast compared to anything you can hope to do as interpreter. That can also be done
using a parser and much simpler syntax directed translation.

**But** If these expressions are all produced by Mathematica they'll have a pretty standard but not complicated structure. In this case I'd guess you could write a regexp-based translator that could map the Mathematica forms into C functions with not a lot of trouble; Perl would be ideal for this.  This gives you an easy to implement, and very fast solution.

For what it is worth, I believe Mathematica has an option to convert Mathematica expressions directly into C.  Seems that that would be worth checking out, too.

Comment: Thank you for your input. The issue is, that I have 100's of MB of expressions to be evaluated many times for different parameters, so direct compilation is not the way to go (I have tried this and one of my SO questions dealt with this problem in a related project). I know it's hard to estimate (and I hadn't time to work on this yet), but would the 10x slower rule of thumb also hold for an evaluation like I've mentioned in my second edit (repeated iteration over sparse arrays)?

Comment: You say direct compilation is not the way to go, but you aren't giving any let alone good reasons other than a vague reference to another project which I'm obviously not privy to.   If you code an interpreter, you'll have an interpreter.  Unless you code it really well (I get the impression this isn't a specific skill you think you have), you'll do worse than the usual 10x.

Comment: ... I looked at your other SO questions; the most obviously relevant was "my object file is > 2 Gb" but you appear to have gotten around that.  So what's the issue with the other solution?  I'll agree with the tone of most of the responses; I think you should reconsider how you got such large numbers of such huge functions in the first place. Nobody wrote all that code; it is being generated somehow.  I think you need to go back to the way it was generated and reconsider why it is generated that way; clearly, it is making the problem harder to solve.

Comment: ... I build code generators/optimizers/compilers for a living, and have some experience with scientific computing and code generation.   I'd be happy to have an offline conversation about this; see my email address in my bio.

Comment: ... your sparse array approach is a way to to approach your interpreter.  I wouldn't expect this to make you interpreter go significantly faster, and the fact that you are suggesting a sparse array (think points and links and test-for-presence) implies memory accesses and conditionals, both things that modern computers do slowly, will be present in your proposed scheme.  Compiled code for these expressions would not have these extra accesses or conditionals.

Comment: Flagger: you could have the courtesy to write a comment here as to your objection to my response, as opposed to  just "flagging" this and running away.  As far as I can see my answer is relevant and appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple example in the [Bison Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Infix-Calc.html#Infix-Calc).

Comment: This gets OP a parser that evaluates the expression as it parses. If OP has to re-evaluate the expression, using this technique will force OP to reparse.  In other comment threads, he said he didn't want to do that.

Comment: If the OP wants to compile the expression into some sort of object tree, the example provides a starting point