# String of operands and operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Evaluating arithmetic expressions in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329406/evaluating-arithmetic-expressions-in-c)

I've created a class that handles rational arithmetic. i.e. has a constructor that accepts strings of the form "a/b", and instantiates an object with object.numerator = a, and object.denominator = b. I've also overload the arithmetic operators to deal with Rational objects.

My question is, I will be reading in lines from a file, such as: "a/b + c/d"

I know how to make sure both operands become Rational objects, but how do I pull the operator from the stream, and use it on the operands?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom interpreter for mathematical expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6713983/), [What is the best way to evaluate mathematical expression in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5115872/), [Evaluating arithmetic expressions in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9329406/)

Comment: ... [How to evaluate any given expression](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10642959/)